# What is the best way for communication between cluster nodes

Tags: c#, vb6, web, service, load-balancing

I have an application written in a combination of ASP/VB6/VBScript and ASP.NET/C# that consists of a website part, SOAP-like webservice part and a queue processing part processing incoming files in a hotfolder.

We are used to running under load balancers (Microsoft or other make). Often we need to communicate between the different load balanced servers. Currently we do this through the SQL Server database that is common for all nodes, however, this comes with a performance penalty as each message requires a transaction and continual polling from the other nodes.

What would be better ways to achieve this?

Comment: Do you require point to point communication so from one node to a specific other node or do you just need to broadcast messages to all the nodes?

Comment: I guess the most common scenario would be broadcasting "clear your cache now" messages to all nodes. Maybe second would be start/stop and other control messages from the web app to the automated services running in other processes. I too would like to see answers.